# PhoneGap processMessage failed: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: cordova

Hi guys I try to find out solution of following error

> (D/CordovaLog(1512): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 981 : processMessage failed: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

On Android same code working fine on Ios device I checked and place all the permissions that needed for filetransfer method as define in documents.

I also install latest version I thought that might resolve the issue but no luck.

I use the following implementation which is define on phonegap documentation.
Here is my source code.

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message){
//alert('get picture failed');
},{
quality: 50, 
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}); 

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="image";
options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
var authtoken = window.localStorage.getItem("authtoken");
var username = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
var userid = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
var spotid = window.localStorage.getItem("spotId");
var  message = private_key + authtoken + username
var md5message = CryptoJS.MD5( message );
//console.log(private_key +":"+ authtoken +":"+ username+":"+userid);
var auth_code = md5message.toString();
//console.log( auth_code );
params.authcode = auth_code;
params.user_id = userid;
params.spot_id = spotid;
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "http://beta.cityisyours.com/api/spot_picture_add", win, fail, options);
```

When I try to upload image using `FileTransfer()`;
Any suggestion

Comment: do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

In navigator.camera.getPicture you are referencing a function named uploadPhoto, have you defined this?

Another problem might be the lack of semicolon on this line:

```
var message = private_key + authtoken + username
```